# Regex doesn't work as expected in Angular Template

Tags: regex, angular2-template, angular8

I'm trying to extract particular sentence from string using regex.

**Input String:**

1. *Property Location With a stay at Al Buraq Hotel in Dubai (Deira), you''ll be steps from Gold Souk and Spice Souk. This hotel is 8.6 mi (13.9 km) from Dubai Mall and 9 mi (14.5 km) from Center.*
2. *Walk of Mall of the Emirates and Ski Dubai.This hotel is 9.1 mi (14.6 km) from Race.*

**Expected Output String:**

1. *This hotel is 8.6 mi (13.9 km) from Dubai Mall*
2. *This hotel is 9.1 mi (14.6 km) from Race.*

**Actual Output String:**

1. *This hotel is 8.6 mi (13.9 km) from*
2. *This hotel is 9.1 mi (14.6 km) from*

Below is my code

**component.ts**

```
regex = /This(.*)hotel(.*)from(.*?)((.)|(?=and))/;
// regex = new RegExp('This(.*)hotel(.*)from(.*?)((.)|(?=and))')
```

**template.html**

```
<div>
    {{hotel.HotelInfo.HotelDescription.match(regex)?hotel.HotelInfo.HotelDescription.match(regex)[0]:null}}
</div>
```

I have tested this regex expression using [this website](https://regex101.com/) and it works fine.

Comment: [Testing on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0fWmtu/1), the provided regex does not match the expected output string, contrary to what you said in your last sentence.

Comment: @CássioRenan Maybe I missed out something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of the pattern `from(.*?)((.)|(?=and))` matches *from*, then  matches any char as least as possible `.*?` followed by matching either any char using a dot `(.)` or `|` assert what is on the right is *and* using a positive lookahead `(?=and)`

In both cases there is a char at the right of *from*, so that will be matched.

You could make the match more specific:

```
\bThis hotel is \d+(?:\.\d+)? mi \(\d+(?:\.\d+)? km\) from .*?(?= and|$)
```

The pattern in parts

- `\bThis hotel is`  Match literally
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `mi`  Match literally
- `\(` Match `(`
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`
- `km) from`  Match literally
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline non greedy
- `(?= and|$)` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is  `and` or the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9ZtNDc/1)

Comment: Thank you. That's well explained answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use non greedy match to stop at the first *from*:

```
This.*hotel.*?from.*?(?= and|$)
```

`.*from` matches with the longest possible text: `is 8.6 mi (13.9 km) from Dubai Mall and 9 mi (14.5 km) from`.

Each part belongs to these texts:

```
This            "This"                    "This"
.*              " "                       " "
hotel           "hotel"                   "hotel"
.*?             " is 8.6 mi (13.9 km) "   " is 9.1 mi (14.6 km) "
from            "from"                    "from"
.*?(?= and|$)   " Dubai Mall"             " Race."
```